# How to prevent Multibinding with MultiValueConverter from getting value several times and with proper parameters

Tags: wpf, multibinding, imultivalueconverter

I want to display time information regarding to a specified time scale (for instance hours, minutes, seconds). This info is displayed within items of a listbox. To do this, I created a custom ControlTemplate for ListBoxItem-s like:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">                      
   <Controls:ExtendedTextBlock x:Name="time" d:LayoutOverrides="Width">
     <Controls:ExtendedTextBlock.Text>
       <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource scaledDateToStringConverter}" FallbackValue="">
          <Binding Path="Time"></Binding>
          <Binding Path="TimelineScale"></Binding>
      </MultiBinding>                       
</ControlTemplate>
```

Converter does the following:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var scale = (TimelineScale)values[1];
        var timestamp = (DateTime)values[0];
        string convertedTimestamp;

        if (timestamp == default(DateTime))
        {
            convertedTimestamp = "LIVE";
        }
        else
        {
            switch (scale)
            {
                case TimelineScale.Seconds:
                    convertedTimestamp = timestamp.ToString("T", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                    break;
                case TimelineScale.Minutes:
                    convertedTimestamp = timestamp.ToString("t", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                    break;
                case TimelineScale.Hours:
                    convertedTimestamp = timestamp.AddMinutes(-timestamp.Minute).AddSeconds(-timestamp.Second).ToString("t", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                    break;
                default:
                    convertedTimestamp = timestamp.ToString("T", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                    break;
            }
        }

        return convertedTimestamp;
    }
```

The problem is that for some items, Convert method is invoked more then one time and at first invocation, instead of actual time value -DependencyProperty.UnsetValue is passed as a parameter, causing InvalidCastException during unboxing the value from an input array. How can I achieve convertation only once and (at least)with valid parameters?

There are some interesting remarks about this issue:
The value of time is defenitely defined.
This code is working for a long time, since .NET ver. 4.0 but the problem appeared only now (at least it started constantly reproducing by customers and our testing machines)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the converter is evaluating as each of the bound properties is set. Therefore, whichever property (`Time` or `TimelineScale`) is set first, the MultiBinding evaluates and the other will have the unset value since it has not been evaluated yet.

There are a couple of ways to handle this.

**Return *UnsetValue***

Add the following to the top of your `Convert` method:

```
if (!(values[1] is TimelineScale) || !(values[0] is DateTime))
{
    return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
}
```

**Use default values**

```
var scale = (values[1] as TimelineScale?).GetValueOrDefault();
var timestamp = (values[0] as DateTime?).GetValueOrDefault();
```

In either case, once the binding evaluates a second time, `Convert` will have the parameters it needs and your MultiBinding will update correctly.

**Edit:** It is possible that you have an upstream binding that is incorrect. I have a co-worker that recently ran into an issue with UnsetValue appearing on a value with a binding where the binding path was misspelled. It is possible this is a new behavior introduced in .NET/WPF 4.0.

Comment: I know about this approach, but just want to avoid execution of additional lines of code there. The collection is a rather big and the app is heavy in general. I would prefer to figure out why is it happening for few items in a list and how to prevent it.

Comment: I don't think you can prevent it - returning UnsetValue will be more performant than letting exceptions happen though.

Comment: You could also use `<Binding Path="X" FallbackValue="Y"/>` on each of the bindings - that would probably replace `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` with a value your converter can handle.

Comment: This idea is much better, it allows converter to be free of redundant validation before type casting, but DependencyProperty.UnsetValue is steel passing to the converter sometimes. I tried `FallbackValue="{x:Static sys:DateTime.MinValue}"`. What is interesting, that in case if an empty string is set as a `FallbackValue`, it realy replaces `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`.

Comment: I've expanded my answer with another possibility. I'm not sure why `FallbackValue` would vary in returning `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` based on whether you use a `string` or a `DateTime`.